# Test of hypothesis, how to find P-value??

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

[image]

Here is my take for $a)$

From the question, I can find:

$$n=124, p = \frac{2}3, np = 82.667 \ge 10, nq = 41.133 \ge 10$$ $$u = np = 82.667, \sigma^2 = npq = 27.5556$$

Test of hypothesis (two-tail): $$ H_0 : p = \frac{2}3 \space \space vs \space \space H_a: p \not= \frac{2}3$$

and I used,

$$z = \frac{p - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}$$

where $p_0 = \frac{2}3, p = \frac{80}{124}$ then i get $$z = -.508$$

Hence, P-value $$= 2P(z\ge -.508)$$ $$=1.478$$

but apparently, the correct answer is $0.6114$

What did I do wrong? Any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you've taken the wrong tail of the standard normal distribution.  You should have calculated $$2 \Pr[Z \le -0.508] = 0.6114.$$  The reason is that if the test statistic you calculate is negative for your test, then you take the probability that $Z$ is less than or equal to this value; if the test statistic is positive, you take the probability that $Z$ is greater than or equal to this value.

Comment: $2 \Pr[Z \le -0.508] = 2 \Pr[Z \ge 0.508] = 2* 1- \Pr[Z \le 0.508]$? but still it doesnt give me 0.6114.. $2(1-0.719)=0.562$

Comment: or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Allie  Using a normal table or a calculator, I have $$\Pr[Z \le 0.508] = 0.694273.$$  How are you getting your cumulative distribution values?

Comment: ah! i was looking at 0.58... sorry for the confusion!